# Preferred request handler interface to implement AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am writing an AWS lambda in Java. Lambda provides two interfaces to implement the request handler.

1. RequestHandler - Uses lambda’s serialization for converting input request to InputPojo and vice versa for output.
2. RequestStreamHandler – Implementor writes serialization-deserialization logic on input/output stream.

I could not find documentation on serialization behavior of Lambda. I am not sure of questions like

- Will the serde ignore unknown properties?
- Will the serde ignore null
  fields?
- How to i specify names of json fields
- Can the above behavior change in future?

I wanted to use Jackson annotations to have more control on this. But the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html) specifically states
“You shouldn't rely on any other features of serialization frameworks such as annotations..“ 
So I am planning to use the second interface.

Before proceeding, given all above, want to check the recommended interface to use? which to use when?

Thanks